# Transposing with Arrays

Tags: arrays, sas

I need to transpose a wide `dataset` into a narrow one using arrays but I'm not sure how. The wide `dataset` looks like this:

```
id name t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
11 Jack 79 83 87 70 98 161
12 John 89 73 87 99 100 170
13 Juan 99 93 93 99 99 186
```

And I need the output to look like this:

```
11 Jack F1 79
11 Jack F2 83
11 Jack F3 87
11 Jack F4 70
11 Jack Q1 98
11 Jack G1 161
12 John F1 89
12 John F2 73
12 John F3 87
12 John F4 99
12 John Q1 100
12 John G1 170
13 Juan F1 99
13 Juan F2 93
13 Juan F3 93
13 Juan F4 99
13 Juan Q1 99
13 Juan G1 186
```

Arrays are a little beyond my expertise so I need a little help.

Comment: How is your question different (other than being simpler) than this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268796/transposing-wide-to-long-with-an-array-in-sas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transposing wide to long with an array in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268796/transposing-wide-to-long-with-an-array-in-sas)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need arrays to transpose this data.  You can use `Proc TRANSPOSE` and the `rename=` data set option on the incoming and outgoing data.

Data

```
data have; input
id name $ t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6; datalines;
11 Jack 79 83 87 70 98 161
12 John 89 73 87 99 100 170
13 Juan 99 93 93 99 99 186
run;
```

Transpose

```
proc transpose 
  data=have (rename=(
      t1=f1
      t2=f2
      t3=f3
      t4=f4
      t5=q1
      t6=g1
  ))
  out=want (rename=(_name_=field col1=value))
;

  by id name notsorted;
  var f1 f2 f3 f4 q1 g1;
run;
```